# How to make auth as user with route id in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I would like to use auth in my login system with two roles:

- admin
- user.

When I redirect the route to user, it fails.

My Controller:

```
public function profile($id)
{
    $santri = Santri::find($id);

    return view('santri.profile', ['santri'=>$santri]);
}
```

My Route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'checkRole:admin,user']], function () {
    Route::get('/santri/{id}/profile', 'SantriController@profile')->name('profiluser');
});
```

How I check the role:

```
{
    $santri = Santri::all();

    if(in_array($request->user()->role,$roles))
    {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect()->route('profiluser', $santri);
}
```

Error:

> Missing required parameters for [Route: profiluser] [URI: santri/{id}/profile].

Answer (score 2):

The error message:

> Missing required parameters for [Route: profiluser] [URI: santri/{id}/profile].

tells you that you are missing the parameter for this route: `profiluser`

As you can see here you do not call the route with the correct parameter, you are trying to pass the whole object instead of the id, so instead of this:

```
return redirect()->route('profiluser', $santri);
```

Do this:

```
return redirect()->route('profiluser', $santri->id);
```

But since you are already passing the whole object you could also do this, lets call it method B.

Here you want to find the model using the passed id:

```
public function profile($id)
{
    $santri = Santri::find($id);

    return view('santri.profile', ['santri'=>$santri]);
}
```

But since you already pass the whole object you could do this:

```
public function profile(Santri $santri)
{
    return view('santri.profile', ['santri' => $santri]);
}
```

or this, which looks cleaner in my mind:

```
public function profile(Santri $santri)
{
    return view('santri.profile', compact('santri'));
}
```

Comment: IMHO you're right but change `public function profile(Santri $santri)` to `public function profile(Santri $id)`, the injected variable name should match the parameter name for implicit binding to work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `$santry->id` instead of just $santry. Change the line to:

```php
return redirect()->route('profiluser', [$santri->id]);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your route:

```
Route::get('/santri/{id}/profile', 'SantriController@profile')->name('profiluser');
```

You must pass the user id, like this:

```
return redirect()->route('profiluser', ['id' => $request->user()->id]);
```